# Angular UI popover with custom options -

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wanting to add some custom options to an Angular UI popover but I'm getting an error saying it's undefined. What am I missing here in order to make this work? I'm using Angular 1.0.8 without Jquery.

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bullrout/c6Eg4/6/)

Cheers, Jimi.

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
 element.popover(options);
```

Comment: Hi, I am struggeling with the same issue. Have you found a solution in meantime?

Answer (score 0):

the `element.popover(options)` is using the bootstrap native API.

I presume you are using the bootstrap components via the angular-ui library, in order to use the above syntax you need to import the native bootstrap.js script.

Comment: That should not be true - "This repository contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required."  While it shouldn't be true, I'm experiencing the exact same problem.